# strDirName = Dir(strParentFolder, vbDirectory)

Tags: vba, ms-access, directory

This code:

```
strDirName = Dir(strParentFolder, vbDirectory)
Do Until strDirName = ""
```

returns files as well folders.  It should only return folders.

Is it possible to use Dir to return a list of subfolders?  Or is it recommended to use FileSystemObject(s)?

Comment: What made you think it should only return folders?

Comment: Based on my quick scan of the documentation available - that's what I expected.

Comment: ...so I need to use FileSystemObject (s) ?

Comment: If you want a method that will **often** work, just perform a check (within your loop) to see if `Instr(strDirName, ".") = 0` - most people don't use a `.` in a directory name but do use it in file names.  (But using a `FileSystemObject` would almost certainly be a more reliable way!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation page "files with no attributes" will also be returned so you may wish to check those.

Dir Function

Applies To: Access 2016

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Dir-Function-1a1a4275-f92f-4ae4-8b87-41e4513bba2e

> vbDirectory 16 Specifies directories or folders in addition to files with no attributes.

Comment: Please also add some explanation, not just a quote from documentation and a link

Comment: I thought I'd just be repeating myself but good point, explaining the statement would be more beneficial

Comment: What would make a really good question is "Why does using just `vbNormal` return files that have the read-only attribute set, but correctly excludes files with the hidden attribute set?" (but let's not go there!! LOL)

Answer (score 0):

I can't make any recommendations on how to do what you're asking using `Dir()` but below is a generic example of how you'd accomplish that using `FileSystemObject.`

This will print a single string of the first level of sub-directories in relation to the root directory.

```
Sub GetFolderList()

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set rootFolder = fso.GetFolder("*Root Directory URI*")
    Set subFolders = rootFolder.subFolders

    Folders = ""
    For Each fld In subFolders
        Folders = Folders & fld.Name
        Folders = Folders & " "
    Next

    Debug.Print Folders

End Sub
```